# Page Layouts inside Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, schema

I am creating a page that let's me create multiple objects at once.  The thing is that I want it to be dynamic so that an admin can modify it simply by changing the standard page layouts to make new fields show up or remove other ones.  The User can also select record types here to change what layout is in use.  Is there an example of how to do this somewhere?  I recall seeing it once, but I can't seem to find an example anywhere via google/stack exchange.

Comment: standard Edit page or standard View page (or both)?

Comment: @cropredy Standard Edit.

Comment: I would have suggested fieldSets but I see you already know this - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/27826/2602 :-) - otherwise, deconstruct pagelayout from metadata api - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm

Comment: @cropredy Yes, those are both options I am currently looking at.  I think I may try using the metadata api.  My front end skills are weaker though making using it a bit harder.  I wanted to stay away from the change set so that an admin doesn't have to do anything special.

Comment: so, you would be using metadata api to generate dynamic VF components a la https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_intro.htm ?  you may have less front end work than you think unless you aren't used to VF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the detail to expose the standard page layout on a visualforce page.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm

Comment: There are no Ids at this point besides for RecordType.  It also needs to put these in edit mod.  I don't think this would help.

Comment: Understood. If you need to create/edit then you might consider using the standard create/edit page but adding a parameter to return you back to your visualforce page once the detail record has been created.   Here is a good description http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-basics-with-returl-saveurl-and-cancelurl.html

Comment: Sorry that doesn't help either.  They want all of the info for multiple objects on a single page so they can eliminate clicks.